# Removing border of a QWidget without affecting its child elements

Tags: linux, qt, stylesheet, qwidget

I need to remove the border of the QWidget without affecting its child elements. If I set border as none for QWidget it will be applied to all its child elements. So I need a way for specifying the border to QWidget alone.

Comment: You have 2 options here. 1. specify exact widget to style: `QWidget#mywidget {border:none;} `. 2. Set some property to your widget and then style all widgets with such property: `QWidget [noborder=true] {border: none}` (you need to add property "noborder" with value "true" to  your widget)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html

Selector types section, 
ID selector or descendant selector

I dont know much about qt css, but would first try to target precisely the desired widget, and if meeting inheritance of the property on childs, add cancelling rules for children.

Answer (score 0):

Using a css file set a general selector on all QWidgets to have no border:

```
QWidget {border-style: none;}
```

Give your parent QWidget a name like this:

```
 setObjectName("myParentWidget").
```

Then finally add an id selector to your stylesheet for that particular widget only like so:

```
#myParentWidget {border-style: 1px black solid;}
```